# Fake HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath for unit test

Tags: c#, unit-testing, httpcontext

I have a test which fails on this line. I've figured out that it is because of the `HttpContext` inside of my `GetProofOfPurchase` method. Here is the line I'm failing on:

```
var image = Image.GetInstance(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(GlobalConfig.HeaderLogo));
```

This is my test:

```
 [Test]
    public void GetProofOfPurchase_Should_Call_Get_On_ProofOfPurchaseRepository()
    {
        string customerNumber = "12345";
        string orderNumber = "12345";
        string publicItemNumber = "12345";

    var result = new ProofOfPurchase();
    this.proofOfPurchaseRepository.Expect(p => p.Get(new KeyValuePair<string,string>[0])).IgnoreArguments().Return(result);
    this.promotionTrackerService.GetProofOfPurchase(customerNumber, orderNumber, publicItemNumber);
    this.promotionTrackerRepository.VerifyAllExpectations();
}
```

The test fails on `promotionTrackerService.GetProofOfPurchase` line. How do I fake the `HttpContext` in this situation? I have searched Stack Overflow for similar issues to mine but I'm unable to get anything to work.

I've tried doing this:

```
var image = Image.GetInstance(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, GlobalConfig.HeaderLogo));
```

But it fails saying:

> System.Net.WebException : Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Images\HeaderLogo.png'.

From what I've read on Stack Overflow I shouldn't be using `HttpContext.Current` if I plan to unit test it, which is why I have tried using `Path.Combine`, but I'm unable to get that to work properly.

Can someone offer some guidance to what I need to do to get this unit test to work?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I prefer to do when writing tests for code involving [non-pure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function) functions is to hide them behind, in simplest cases, plain old `Func<string, string>`:

```
class PromotionTrackerService
{
    private readonly Func<string, string> imageMapper;

    public PromotionTrackerService(Func<string, string> imageMapper)
    {
        this.imageMapper = imageMapper ?? HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath;
    }

    public void GetProofOfPurchase()
    {
        var image = Image.GetInstance(imageMapper(GlobalConfig.HeaderLogo));
    }
}
```

Now, your test does not look like a *unit* test -- it's more of an *integration* test, with all that file access and all.